# Is it necessary to submit a form wrapped by a blob ? and what's the best practice?

Tags: javascript, java, forms, spring-boot

I'm setting up a website page, and want to submit a form with multiple fields, and the Back-end API handles the request is prepared.

Simplified Code shows below:

```html
<form id="contact-form" @submit="postForm" ref="aGeniusForm">
 <input type="text" name="companyName">
 <input type="email" name="email">
 <textarea type="text" name="question"></textarea>
 <input type="file" name="file">
<form>
```

The Back-End is powered by Sprint Boot, and the Controller code is:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/emails")
class EmailController(
    val emailService: EmailService,
    val objectMapper: ObjectMapper
){
    @PostMapping("/applications", consumes = ["multipart/form-data"])
    @ApiOperation("Send a apply email")
    fun sendApplyEmail(
        @RequestPart body: ApplyEmailPostDto,
        @RequestPart("files", required = false) files: List<MultipartFile>
    ): EmptyResponse {
        emailService.sendApplyEmail(body, files)
        return EmptyResponse
    }
}
```

The front-end code that creates an http request, the trouble is in `postForm` method.

```
// Form component data 
export default {
  name: "SignupForm",
  components: {},
  data() {
  return {
    return {
      form: {
        companyName: "",
        email: "",
        question: ""
      },
      files: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    postForm() {
    let formData = new FormData(); 
    // Blob is the point ↓ ↓ ↓
    formData.append(
          "body",
          new Blob([JSON.stringify(this.form)], {
            type: "application/json"
          })
    ))
    // It is the point ↑ ↑ ↑
    // post request, "multipart/form-data"
    axios.post(
            URL,
            formData, // the data to post
            {
              headers: {
                "Content-type": "multipart/form-data"
              }
            }
          )
          .then(response => {
            //...
          })
          .catch(error => {
            //...
          });
    }
  }
```

I know that `Blob` is not widely supported in mobile browsers and in webviews and I don't think using `Blob` is necessary.
But back-end developer insisted on making me do so.

If front-end code as below

```
formData.append("body",this.form))
//or
formData.append("body",JSON.stringify(this.form)))
```

The Back-end API return code `400` with message: `"media-type not supported"`

The kotlin developer who designed the API declared that he cannot support other media-type easily.

I'm not quite familiar with `Spring Boot` framework or kotlin. So I need you guys to tell me is that true?

What's the best practice for this condition？